Modeling minimal surface with cusps
This question is already asked in MSE, but haven't got any answer so I'm asking here again.

As far as I understood, minimal surface can be determined by its boundary (generically), by solving the corresponding PDE (Lagrange's equation). Now I want to give additional constraints on the surface: fix finite points on the surface and "pulling" them to certain directions with threads. For example, imagine a disk bounded by a circle, and we put a thread at the center of the disk & pull the thread to a certain direction, so that surface has a shape of curved cone or black hole. I wonder if we can still formulate a corresponding PDE that determines the surface, with given points and directions of threads. (Disclaimer: I'm not a geometer or physicist and I know basic graduate level differential geometry and some PDE.)
